# Display Local notifications in custom time intervals

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone.I am working with below code,here the local notification does not fire with in 10sec as well as repeat interval also not work,it does not show the notification in every second.After 1 minute firedate calls and in the same way repeat interval works for every one minute.how can set the repeat interval to every 15 sec.If anybody know this please help me...

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"1");

   NSTimeInterval interval = 10;
    NSDate *alertTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:interval];
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UILocalNotification* notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (notifyAlarm){
        notifyAlarm.fireDate = alertTime;

        notifyAlarm.alertAction = @"Message";
        notifyAlarm.alertBody = @"Alert";
        notifyAlarm.hasAction = YES;
        notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = NSSecondCalendarUnit;
      //  timer = [[NSTimer alloc]initWithFireDate:alertTime interval:interval target:self selector:@selector(sendRequest) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];

        }
```

Comment: what you wont give your clear idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this in the appDelegate for the notification to work while the app is running.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    //do something
}
```